# Exchange 2010 server randomly fails to decode pdf

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

Problem:  Exchange 2010 randomly fails to decode a pdf.

I have a new(ish) third party that submits completed PDF forms in an email for mobile users - but the issue just started last week.  Here's what happens:

- Not every PDF from the same mailer is affected.
- Sometimes, the same
  PDF from the same message cannot be opened in some mailboxes. (IE:
  everyone can open the attachment, except if you retrieve it from a
  public folder.  Other times, this doesn't matter)
- Resending the email
  often fixes the issue.
- Opening all attachments in my spam filter
  allows the item to be read, without issue.
- It appears decoding stops
  at the end of Page 1 (of 2) of the document.
- Issue persists
  regardless of workstation, or client.  (Happens in Outlook 2010,
  2013, 365, and WebApp.)
- PDF cannot be opened "There was an error opening this document.  The file is damaged and cannot be repaired."

Seem to find many people having a similar issue, but not a solution.  I cannot receive the PDFs in a .zip, as they are generated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause for these problems is one of two...

1. A poor PDF creator. This happens more often that you might think - particularly where a third party PDF tool is being used (ie not an Adobe one). I have had it happen with copiers, scanners etc.
2. Third party interference - spam filter or file level AV scanning something it shouldn't be. If you have AV on the server ensure that it has the correct exclusions on it. Exchange integrated tools can also cause this problem. It will not be an Exchange itself.

Comment: I have them on every whitelist I can.  I also need to rephrase the scenario then - I create the PDF in adobe to distribute, then its filled in and submitted via 3rd party.

Comment: Whitelisting doesn't really help. All that means is the product doesn't take any action against the file - it is still scanning it. If you have third party products on the server then unfortunately the only way to confirm they are not responsible is to remove them. Disabling them is not enough - as they still have their hooks. They have to be removed and the server rebooted.

Comment: It is a third party service not on my server directly.

Comment: You have no other third party products on the Exchange server at all? No AV, signature management etc?